# Seed did not work but migrate work perfectly

Tags: php, laravel

I try to make a modular Laravel application. 
I use [laravel-modules-example](https://github.com/bstrahija/laravel-modules-example) for beginning point of my project. 
Now I have a problem to call seed from install module.

```
Artisan::call('migrate', array('--env' => App::environment()));
```

works perfeclty-create all needed tables, which are placed 
into "app/database/migrate" folder. 
But when I call

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

to seed database files which is placed into "app/database/seeds", that result nothing. What I do wrong?

Comment: What is the output of **php artisan db:seed -vvv**?

Comment: In cmd: just list of modules

Comment: where to put php artisan db:seed -vvv command?

Comment: Execute it in the command line in the base of your laravel installation.

Comment: Here is a part of return:
[2014-03-14 11:43:26] production.DEBUG: [MODULES] Module "roles" has been registered. [] []
[2014-03-14 11:43:26] production.DEBUG: [MODULES] Module "settings" has been registered. [] []
[2014-03-14 11:43:26] production.DEBUG: [MODULES] Module "users" has been registered. [] []
[2014-03-14 11:43:26] production.DEBUG: [MODULES] Module "install" has been regi
stered. [] []